# Azure Graph API - ClaimsMappingPolicy with ClaimsTransformation

Tags: azure, saml, claims-based-identity, azure-ad-graph-api

Im trying to automate the configuration of an enterpise application via the Azure Graph API.
Specifically, its the Azure Palo Alto Admin UI - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/saas-apps/paloaltoadmin-tutorial#configure-azure-ad-sso

Ive managed to get this working via the frontend, but im having trouble configuring the custom claims via the Graph Api.

For now, i just want to use a string claim in the custom claim as the `customadmin` value with a hardcoded value for the admin role
[image: Azure Palo Alto Admin UI SAML Claim]

When creating via the portal, you can easily enter a string value as the source type of the claim.
However, via the Graph API the source type must be `user`, `resource`, `audience`, `company` or `transformation`.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-claims-mapping#claim-schema-entry-elements

It seems that you can create a `string` type of `transformation` and then link the transformation into the main `ClaimsSchema`.

There is a similar example documented here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/claimsmappingpolicy?view=graph-rest-1.0#example-definition-that-uses-a-claims-transformation
But I cannot get the example to work. Even with a bit of massaging, the example fails. This is what ive been trying:

```
cat <<- EOF > claims.json
{
  "definition": [
    "{\"ClaimsMappingPolicy\":{
        \"Version\":1,
        \"IncludeBasicClaimSet\":\"true\",
        \"ClaimsSchema\":[
        {\"Source\":\"user\",\"ID\":\"extensionattribute1\"},{\"Source\":\"transformation\",\"ID\":\"DataJoin\",\"TransformationId\":\"JoinTheData\",\"JwtClaimType\":\"JoinedData\"}
        ],
         \"ClaimsTransformation\":[
        {\"ID\":\"JoinTheData\",\"TransformationMethod\":\"Join\",\"InputClaims\":[{\"ClaimTypeReferenceId\":\"extensionattribute1\",\"TransformationClaimType\":\"string1\"}], \"InputParameters\": [{\"ID\":\"string2\",\"Value\":\"sandbox\"},{\"ID\":\"separator\",\"Value\":\".\"}],\"OutputClaims\":[{\"ClaimTypeReferenceId\":\"DataJoin\",\"TransformationClaimType\":\"outputClaim\"}]}
        ]
    }}"
  ],
  "displayName": "Azure Reference Claim",
  "isOrganizationDefault": false
}
EOF
az rest --method post --headers Content-type="application/json" --url "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/policies/claimsMappingPolicies" --body @claims.json
```

Ive tried both the `v1.0` and `beta` APIs but they both have the same behaviour

Which returns with the following error:

```
Bad Request({
  "error": {
    "code": "Request_BadRequest",
    "message": "Property  has an invalid value.",
    "innerError": {
      "date": "2020-09-01T13:03:10",
      "request-id": "bc7cf58e-fe6d-47d1-b1e5-cae43326864f"
    }
  }
})
```

I was able to get the rest of the Palo Alto claim working (excluding the custom string) with the following:

```
{
  "definition": [
    "{\"ClaimsMappingPolicy\":{
        \"Version\":1,
        \"IncludeBasicClaimSet\":\"true\",
         \"ClaimsSchema\": [{\"Source\":\"user\",\"ID\":\"userprincipalname\",\"SamlClaimType\":\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier\"},{\"Source\":\"user\",\"ID\":\"givenname\",\"SamlClaimType\":\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/givenname\"},{\"Source\":\"user\",\"ID\":\"displayname\",\"SamlClaimType\":\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name\"},{\"Source\":\"user\",\"ID\":\"surname\",\"SamlClaimType\":\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/surname\"},{\"Source\":\"user\",\"ID\":\"userprincipalname\",\"SamlClaimType\":\"username\"}]
         }}"
  ],
  "displayName": "Palo Alto Claims Policy",
  "isOrganizationDefault": false
}
```

And i was able to create a CustomString transformation which isnt linked to anything with the following:

```
{
  "definition": [
    "{\"ClaimsMappingPolicy\":{
      \"Version\":1,
      \"IncludeBasicClaimSet\":\"true\",
      \"ClaimsTransformation\":[{\"ID\":\"CreateTermsOfService\",\"TransformationMethod\":\"CreateStringClaim\",\"InputParameters\": [{\"ID\":\"value\",\"DataType\":\"string\", \"Value\":\"sandbox\"}],\"OutputClaims\":[{\"ClaimTypeReferenceId\":\"TOS\",\"TransformationClaimType\":\"createdClaim\"}]}]
    }}",
    ],
    "displayName": "sdfa",
    "isOrganizationDefault": false
}
```

However, when i try them together in the format of the example I get an error.

```
{
  "definition": [
    "{\"ClaimsMappingPolicy\":{
        \"Version\":1,
        \"IncludeBasicClaimSet\":\"true\",
        \"ClaimsSchema\": [
            {\"Source\":\"user\",\"ID\":\"userprincipalname\",\"SamlClaimType\":\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier\"},{\"Source\":\"user\",\"ID\":\"givenname\",\"SamlClaimType\":\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/givenname\"},{\"Source\":\"user\",\"ID\":\"displayname\",\"SamlClaimType\":\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name\"},{\"Source\":\"user\",\"ID\":\"surname\",\"SamlClaimType\":\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/surname\"},{\"Source\":\"user\",\"ID\":\"userprincipalname\",\"SamlClaimType\":\"username\"},{\"Source\":\"transformation\",\"TransformationID\":\"xxxxxxxxx\",\"ID\":\"DataJoin\",\"SamlClaimType\":\"test\"}
        ],
        \"ClaimsTransformation\":[
            {\"ID\":\"xxxxxxxxx\",\"TransformationMethod\":\"CreateStringClaim\",\"InputParameters\": [{\"ID\":\"value\",\"DataType\":\"string\", \"Value\":\"sandbox\"}],\"OutputClaims\":[{\"ClaimTypeReferenceId\":\"DataJoin\",\"TransformationClaimType\":\"createdClaim\"}]}
        ]
    }}"
  ],
  "displayName": "Palo Alto Claims Policy",
  "isOrganizationDefault": false
}
```

Which returns the same unhelpful error:

```
Bad Request({
  "error": {
    "code": "Request_BadRequest",
    "message": "Property  has an invalid value.",
    "innerError": {
      "date": "2020-09-01T13:03:10",
      "request-id": "bc7cf58e-fe6d-47d1-b1e5-cae43326864f"
    }
  }
})
```

Any ideas what i am doing wrong? Im trying to base off of the example, which i cant get working.
I do not want to use powershell, i want to be able to automate via my desktop terminal.

I imagine i can avoid this situation and get the PA to integrate with AAD without a hardcoded value, but i feel that i should be able to get this working this way.

The mandatory encoding of the `ClaimMappingPolicy` object makes it quite fiddely to develop, so its possible there is a problem there somewhere.
Ive also tried just creating the `ClaimsSchema` without the `ClaimsTransformation` and then running a `PATCH` to amend the object with the transformed object, but it just overwrites the whole `ClaimsMappingPolicy` object rather than adding just the extra field.

When I remove the transformation source from the `ClaimsSchema` the request succeeds.

```
cat <<- EOF > claims.json
{
  "definition": [
    "{\"ClaimsMappingPolicy\":{
        \"Version\":1,
        \"IncludeBasicClaimSet\":\"true\",
        \"ClaimsSchema\": [
            {\"Source\":\"user\",\"ID\":\"userprincipalname\",\"SamlClaimType\":\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier\"},{\"Source\":\"user\",\"ID\":\"givenname\",\"SamlClaimType\":\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/givenname\"},{\"Source\":\"user\",\"ID\":\"displayname\",\"SamlClaimType\":\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name\"},{\"Source\":\"user\",\"ID\":\"surname\",\"SamlClaimType\":\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/surname\"},{\"Source\":\"user\",\"ID\":\"userprincipalname\",\"SamlClaimType\":\"username\"}
        ],
        \"ClaimsTransformation\":[
           {\"ID\":\"xxxxxxxxx\",\"TransformationMethod\":\"CreateStringClaim\",\"InputParameters\": [{\"ID\":\"value\",\"DataType\":\"string\", \"Value\":\"sandbox\"}],\"OutputClaims\":[{\"ClaimTypeReferenceId\":\"DataJoin\",\"TransformationClaimType\":\"createdClaim\"}]}
        ]
    }}"
  ],
  "displayName": "Palo Alto Claims Policy",
  "isOrganizationDefault": false
}
EOF
```

But there isnt an association between the `ClaimsSchema` and the `ClaimsTransformation`. This hints at a problem with the `ClaimsSchema` object

```
{\"Source\":\"transformation\",\"TransformationID\":\"xxxxxxxxx\",\"ID\":\"DataJoin\",\"SamlClaimType\":\"test\"}
```

But this looks suitable when looking at the documentation and the (possibly broken) reference example.

Comment: Have the same issue. Looks like this endpoint is still in change.

Comment: I managed to unblock my specific problem by creating a role with the APIm assigning it to a user with the API and then using the `user.assignedroles` claim. It dosent really solve this specific problem of using a hardcoded string based claim though.

Answer (score 2):

Providing information in answer as its too long to comment it.Please try this below query in Graph explorer

**Post** `https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/policies/claimsMappingPolicies`

```
 {"definition":["{\"ClaimsMappingPolicy\":{\"Version\":1,\"IncludeBasicClaimSet\":\"true\", \"ClaimsSchema\":[{\"Source\":\"user\",\"ID\":\"extensionattribute1\"},{\"Source\":\"transformation\",\"ID\":\"DataJoin\",\"TransformationId\":\"JoinTheData\",\"JwtClaimType\":\"JoinedData\"}],\"ClaimsTransformations\":[{\"ID\":\"JoinTheData\",\"TransformationMethod\":\"Join\",\"InputClaims\":[{\"ClaimTypeReferenceId\":\"extensionattribute1\",\"TransformationClaimType\":\"string1\"}], \"InputParameters\": [{\"ID\":\"string2\",\"Value\":\"sandbox\"},{\"ID\":\"separator\",\"Value\":\".\"}],\"OutputClaims\":[{\"ClaimTypeReferenceId\":\"DataJoin\",\"TransformationClaimType\":\"outputClaim\"}]}]}}"],"displayName":"TestclaimsPolicy","isOrganizationDefault":false}
```

[image]

**Post** `https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/policies/claimsMappingPolicies`

```
{"definition":["{\"ClaimsMappingPolicy\":{\"Version\":1,\"IncludeBasicClaimSet\":\"true\",\"ClaimsSchema\": [{\"Source\":\"user\",\"ID\":\"userprincipalname\",\"SamlClaimType\":\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier\"},{\"Source\":\"user\",\"ID\":\"givenname\",\"SamlClaimType\":\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/givenname\"},{\"Source\":\"user\",\"ID\":\"displayname\",\"SamlClaimType\":\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name\"},{\"Source\":\"user\",\"ID\":\"surname\",\"SamlClaimType\":\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/surname\"},{\"Source\":\"user\",\"ID\":\"userprincipalname\",\"SamlClaimType\":\"username\"}],\"ClaimsTransformation\":[{\"ID\":\"CreateTermsOfService\",\"TransformationMethod\":\"CreateStringClaim\",\"InputParameters\": [{\"ID\":\"value\",\"DataType\":\"string\", \"Value\":\"sandbox\"}],\"OutputClaims\":[{\"ClaimTypeReferenceId\":\"TOS\",\"TransformationClaimType\":\"createdClaim\"}]}]}}"],"displayName":"Test1234","isOrganizationDefault":false}
```

[image]

for more information on CreateTermsOfService please refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/Azure/active-directory-b2c/string-transformations)

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer but you are not using 'CreateStringClaim'. In your example, you are extending the `user` source `extensionattribute1` with a random string which is not what i am trying to do. Thanks.

Comment: Updated answer. Please let us know if it helps.